# No trae toda la informacion al descargar un rtf en asp

Tags: sql-server, asp, rtf

estoy haciendo una descarga de documentos que viene generada de base de datos sqlserver, todo lo que necesito lo estoy realizando, pero cuando voy a generar mi archivo .rtf, no me trae toda la información que necesito

```
sSQL="SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTOS WHERE ID=1"
Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQL)
ID = rs("ID")
sSQL="SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTOS ANEXOS WHERE DOCUMENTO_ID='" & ID & "' "
Set rsC = Conn.Execute(sSQL)
While (Not rsC.EOF)
    ORDEN = rsC("ORDEN")
    GUION = rsC("GUION")
rsC.MoveNext
Wend

archivooriginal= Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") & "plantillas_contratos/DOCUMENTOS.rtf" 
archivonuevo= request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") & Archivo
Set original = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
Set nuevo = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
Set fich = original.OpenTextFile(archivooriginal) 
texto_fichero = fich.readAll() 
fich.Close()

'reemplazamos las variables
texto_fichero = Replace(texto_fichero,"@ ORDEN ", ORDEN)
texto_fichero = Replace(texto_fichero,"@ GUION ", GUION)

Set fich = nuevo.CreateTextFile(archivonuevo) 
fich.Write(texto_fichero) 
fich.Close()
Response.Redirect(Archivo)
```

Cuando le hago un 'response.Write(GUION) me trae toda la informacion que tengo en la base de datos, que son 10 registros

```
While (Not rsC.EOF)
    ORDEN = rsC("ORDEN")
    GUION = rsC("GUION")
rsC.MoveNext
```

Pero cuando genero el .rtf solo me trae un registro y no los 10. De verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal para que no me traiga toda la info

Comment: ¿Cómo guardas al archivo?

Comment: A que te refieres a como guardo el archivo?

Comment: Existe una posibilidad que estés guardando el archivo incompleto, motivo por el cual traes los datos incompletos

Comment: En realidad he puesto todo el codigo que tengo y la forma en que lo guardo, como dije cuando abro el archivo me llega la info, pero incompleta, me muestra solo un dato en vez de los 10 que envio

Comment: ¿Has colocado breakpoints para verificar en qué momento se pierden?

Comment: No, y breakpoints en que parte de mi codigo debo ponerlo? y eso va con alguna variable incorporada?